# How to camouflage at the best on internet?

Tags: proxy

What it would be a decent setup to cover your traces on internet and still having a decent connection?

SSL?
Proxy?
Private VPN?

Comment: It depends who you are trying to hide from. The remote hosts you connect to? Your ISP? Other users of your machine? Other users of your local network? The government? Law enforcement?

Answer (score 2):

So you are looking for anonymity over the internet. Just remember you can not hide yourself over the internet completely but you can definitely make things difficult for the people who are tracking you.

**Using a proxy**

All the requests made by your browser will go to a proxy server and the proxy server makes request for web resources on your behalf. if you are routing your traffic through a proxy then your IP address is hidden from the internet (beyond the proxy). Logs of web servers and ISP routers will reveal only the IP address of the proxy server. There are several websites out there (proxy sites) which do it for you.

You will find many applications out there who will do this for you but remember you are being logged by the proxy itself. This by no means is going to secure you from being caught because these services will share their logs with authorities when asked to do so.

**Proxy Switching**

You can use a tool like [ProxySwitcher](http://www.proxyswitcher.com/) to switch between multiple proxies as you do your thing over the internet. There are many countries in the world (read China) where people set up proxies and these proxies are alive for a very short duration (difficult to find logs) . So basically the source of traffic changes from Australia to China and then to Africa in a matter of seconds.

**The Onion Router project**

(from Wikipedia)

> Tor directs Internet traffic through a free, worldwide volunteer
>   network consisting of thousands of relays to conceal a user's location
>   or usage from anyone conducting network surveillance or traffic
>   analysis.

Basically you have to install a TOR client browser which makes requests to a random TOR node
(Onion router) and your IP is exposed to the first node only. This node asks another node to relay the traffic. This goes on till the traffic reaches its destination. The destination sees that the request is coming from the last TOR node.

In this case no single node knows the complete route. The client finds out the route and gets the public keys for all the nodes. Your message is encrypted with all the keys starting from the key of the last node (hence the name Onion).

In such case you never know who you are trusting (proxies and TOR nodes). I have heard the governments setting up TOR nodes to catch the cyber criminals. All I want to say is don't do anything stupid because you can only delay the trace you can't get away with it.

Comment: I never asked this question :S